# Can we get a configurationClient and/or secretClient from a configuration builder object in AzureFunction .net core?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

I was working on a project which required me to create Keyvault reference in azure AppConfiguration, add/update secrets in KeyVault and to access values in AppConfiguration using Configuration.
Currently, I'm using :

-ConfigurationClient to create key Vault reference.

-SecretClient to add/update secrets in KeyVault.

-Configuration build using the builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration().build() to access values in AppConfiguration.(using builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration() is a necessity due to its features).

So, basically 3 connections to azure are made here. Is there any way to decrease the no. of connections? Like, using the ConfigurationBuilder to get a ConfigurationClient and/or SecretClient.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application is accessing two different resources, App Configuration and Key Vault, a minimum of two connections are needed. This is due to lack of support for shared connections across different services.

Assuming your application is using `ConfigureKeyVault` to access Key Vault references, the call to `AddAzureAppConfiguration().Build()` is actually creating two connections - one to App Configuration and the other to Key Vault. In this case, there are a total of 4 connections. You can reduce it to 3 by registering the `SecretClient` you created to add/update secrets in Key Vault in the `AddAzureAppConfiguration` method.

```cs
SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("http://my-keyvault-uri"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.Connect(settings["connection_string"])
            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv => kv.Register(secretClient));
});
```

At this time, there isn't a supported way to provide an existing instance of `ConfigurationClient` while setting up the `AddAzureAppConfiguration` method, but this may be supported in the future.

Comment: Yup, I'm already using the register method. I was thinking if there was any similar way to pass in configuration client in the builder instead of the configuration string.

Comment: At this time, there isn't a public method to pass in a configuration client. The only possible way I see is to update the internal property `AzureAppConfigurationOptions.Client` using reflection, but I wouldn't recommend that approach. We will consider adding a public method to provide a custom instance of the client in a future release.

Comment: Well, Yeah reflection approach won't be the right thing to do I agree, It looks like I would be going fr the normal method. Thanks by the way :)